# Is it possible to select top 10 items and put the rest of the items in others? Just like we can do in SQL

Tags: google-query-language

Is it possible to create a google query to select top 10 items and group the rest in others category just like we can do with SQL. I am trying to pull the data from Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: Could you give an example? From what I can understand you can do this in 3 steps. 1. Take first 10 (use order by, limit 10), 2. take the rest to a different column(use order by, offset 10) and hide the column, 3. make group by query from the rest and put it below the top 10

Comment: And my google query - SELECT AB, sum(C) where month(B)=month(now()) and year(B)=year(now()) group by AB

I would I add limit and offset to it and then show the rest of the items in Others. I am trying to use this query to create a google chart.

Comment: Please take a look at the anwser I provided. The column names should be changed for sure, but the idea will be the same. I don't want to do the whole task for you :)

Comment: Thank you @lukaszberwid! I will try it out. :)

Comment: if this solves your question please mark the answer as accepted, good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @lukaszberwid for your help! I was able to use the step to get the data. if you do not mind, one last question, it is possible to select the highest value items when selecting top 10 from the sheet? For example : 20,15,12,10...

Comment: when you do this "select A order by A limit 10" the items are selected in order by A, it's possible that you order by something else "select ids order by workhours limit 10", the column names are different, but you get the idea

Comment: Thank you @lukaszberwid again! I was able to get the final result the way I wanted. I really appreciate your help.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an example just to get you started with the Google sheets queering

1. You have to separate top 10 from the group by part. Do a separate sheet take all records except top 10

```
=QUERY(Hours!A2:BC18, "select A, B order by A offset 10")
```

2. Create result sheet. In the first cell paste this query, this will give you top 10 rows

```
=QUERY(Hours!A2:BC18, "select A order by A limit 10")
```

Next in the cell in row 11, paste this query (ExcludingTop10 is sheet created in step 1)

```
=QUERY(ExcludingTop10!A1:B7, "select MAX(A) GROUP BY B")
```

The output would be similar to the following

```
1148002773
1148003048
1148003741
1148005962
1148006591
1148007576
1148007609
1148039351
1148050401
1148050580
max <- you can hide this cell as well
1148079677
```

You have 2 sheets one with all data and the other with summary.